# Can I use a formatted external hard drive on Windows?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8, external-hdd

I want to format a new external hard drive from Ubuntu and was wondering can I later use it on my windows system to transfer files?

Comment: Yes provided you format it as NTFS or FAT, which is possible from Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use it later provided that the file system is FAT32. I have tried three file systems including NTFS and I was only able to access the drive on Xubuntu, Windows 10 and Hisense TV using FAT32.

HTH

Comment: NTFS should work fine. And what was the other one you tried?